# The type int must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter

Tags: c#

i have a simple code, when i change the line `my.Test<int>();` 
to `my.Test<string>();` , it works but it does not work for int.

```
class Program
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public void Test<T>()
            where T : class     // Generic Constraint
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello"); // Prints Hello
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass my = new MyClass();
        my.Test<int>();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: `where T : class`. [`int` is a `struct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx).

Comment: I mean.. You literally have a generic constraint that says the type parameter should be a class.

Comment: My gasoline car doesn't work when I try to put diesel in it. Why is this?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Seems broken. Perhaps buy a new one.

Comment: How come it works for string my.Test<string>(); but not for int ? Is string the same as a class ?

Answer (score 5):

In your code you have

```
where T : class
```

And int is not a class. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: And how to solve his real problem: make it accept both ints and string? Just remove the where, as long as there's no real reason for that constraint? Or replace class with struct...?